# Skip row with particular id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to skip one record from mysql using php when that record match with a variable value.

The `$row['uni_id']` is id in a row of my database table and `$_SESSION['uid']` stores a id in session. When the ids match, that record should be skipped. But it's not working. Do you see the issue?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC )){
    if ($row['uni_id'] == $_SESSION['uid']){
        continue;
    }
    $_SESSION['new_img']=$row['pic_add'];enter code here
    $image= $row['pic_add']; 
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo "{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}";
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row['street'];
    echo "</td><td>";  
    echo $row['city'];  
    echo "</td><td>"; 
}
mysql_free_result($res);
```

Comment: About 150 years ago PHP's mysql_ API became deprecated. Embrace modernity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code ?

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC )){
    if ($row['uni_id'] != $_SESSION['uid']){
        $_SESSION['new_img'] = $row['pic_add'];
        $image= $row['pic_add']; 
        echo "<tr><td>"; 
        echo "{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}";
        echo "</td><td>";   
        echo $row['street'];
        echo "</td><td>";  
        echo $row['city'];  
        echo "</td><td>"; 
    }       
}
 mysql_free_result($res); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using condition in a wrong manner.

Below code might help you.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC )){
if ($row['uni_id'] == $_SESSION['uid']){
    // do nothing
}
else{ 
    $_SESSION['new_img']=$row['pic_add'];
    $image= $row['pic_add']; 
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo "{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}";
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row['street'];
    echo "</td><td>";  
    echo $row['city'];  
    echo "</td><td>"; 
}
```

}

```
mysql_free_result($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust your MySQL query before you start processing the result in PHP.

The solution will depend on your query. If your query is something like this:

```
select * from table
```

You should update it to:

```
select * from table WHERE uid <> "$_SESSION['uid']"
```

If you cannot control the MySQL query, then you can change your PHP code:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC )){

        if ($row['uni_id'] != $_SESSION['uid']){

        $_SESSION['new_img']=$row['pic_add'];enter code here
        $image= $row['pic_add']; 
         echo "<tr><td>"; 
      echo "{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}";
      echo "</td><td>";   
      echo $row['street'];
      echo "</td><td>";  
     echo $row['city'];  
      echo "</td><td>"; 
       }
    }
    mysql_free_result($res);
```

Comment: Good idea, but please  use prepared statements to disable SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC )){

    if ($row['uni_id'] != $_SESSION['uid']){

    $_SESSION['new_img']=$row['pic_add'];
    $image= $row['pic_add']; 
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo "{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}";
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row['street'];
    echo "</td><td>";  
    echo $row['city'];  
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    }
}
    mysql_free_result($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code fragment

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $t='';
        if($row['uni_id'] != $_SESSION['uid'])
        {
            $_SESSION['new_img']=$row['pic_add'];//enter code here
            $image= $row['pic_add'];
            $t.="<tr>";
            $t.="<td>{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}</td>";
            $t.="<td>".$row['street']."</td>";
            $t.="<td>".$row['city']."</td>";
            $t.="</tr>";
        }
        echo $t;
    }
    mysql_free_result($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC )){

  if ($row['uni_id'] !== $_SESSION['uid']){

    $_SESSION['new_img']=$row['pic_add'];
    $image= $row['pic_add']; 
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo "{$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}";
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row['street'];
    echo "</td><td>";  
    echo $row['city'];  
    echo "</td><td>"; 

  }

}
mysql_free_result($res);
```

**NOTE:** Do not use mysql. Its deprecated. Use PDO.